# Why would a newly created record not show up in a list?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a form that creates a record, then transitions to the list of resources for a particular object. However once the record is created, it is not reflected in the list of resources. If I refresh the page, the record is saved in the correct place. I have the ember chrome extension installed and if I look under Resources, then the resource is there pointing to the correct Badge. But if I go to badge first, and look for resources, it is not listed. Any ideas? I would be happy to provide any more information necessary to clarify. Thank you in advance

## Create Resource Form Controller and Route

#### Controller

```
    App.ResourcesCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  resourceTypes: ["link","file","video"],
  needs: ['badge','resourcesIndex'],

  actions: {
    save: function() {

      //Gather the info from the form
      var description = this.get('description');
      var url = this.get('url');
      var type = this.get('type');
      var text = this.get('text');
      var badge = this.get('controllers.badge').get('model');

      //set the data to the model of the route (ResourceCreateRoute)
      var resource = this.get('model');
      console.log(resource);
      resource.set('description',description);
      resource.set('url',url);
      resource.set('type',type);
      resource.set('text',text);
      resource.set('badge',badge);

      var self = this;

      //save the route
      var a = resource.save().then(function() {

        //if success
        //this.get('store').reload();
        console.log('%c that resource saved rather nicely','color:green;');

        self.transitionToRoute('resources.index',self.badge);

      }, function() {

        //if failure
        console.log('%c Yea boss...that didnt go so hot', 'color:red;');
        self.set('isError',true);
      });

    },
    reset: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('resources.index');
    }
  }


});
```

#### Route

```
App.ResourcesCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('resource');
    }
})
```

#### List Resources Route

```
App.ResourcesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.modelFor('badge').get('resources');
    }
});
```

---

## Models

#### Resource Model

```
App.Resource = DS.Model.extend({
    'badge': DS.belongsTo('badge'),
    'text': attr('string'),
    'url': attr('string'),
    'description': attr('string'),
    'type': attr('string')
});
```

#### Badge Model

```
App.Badge = DS.Model.extend({
    'category': DS.belongsTo('category'),
    'title': attr('string'),
    'type': attr('string'),
    'ord': attr('number'),
    'short_description': attr('string'),
    'full_description': attr('string'),
    'mentor': DS.belongsTo('employee'),
    'parent':DS.belongsTo('badge'),
    'icon': attr('string'),
    'required': attr('boolean'),
    'signoff_role': attr('string'),
    'created_at': attr('string'),
    'updated_at': attr('string'),
    'resources': DS.hasMany('resource', { async: true } ),
    'quiz': DS.belongsTo('quiz', { async: true } )
});
```

---

## Templates

#### List of Resources

```
{{#link-to "resources.create" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"}} Create Resource {{icon "plus"}}{{/link-to}}
<h3>Resources</h3>
<dl>
    {{#each  resource in controller}}
        {{render resources/resource resource}}
    {{else}}
        <p class="lead text-muted">There are no resources</p>
    {{/each}}
</dl>
```

#### Resource Item Template

```
{{#if isEditing}}
    <div {{bindAttr class="controller.isError:alert-danger:alert-info :alert"}}>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-2">
            <small>Type</small>
                {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="resourceTypes" classNames="form-control" valueBinding="type"}}
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-10">
                <small>Resource Name</small>
                {{input valueBinding="text" class="form-control"}}
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-12">
            <br>
                <small>Description</small>
                {{textarea valueBinding="description" rows="5" class="form-control"}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-12">
                <br>
                <small>URL,File Name, or Vimeo ID</small>
                {{input valueBinding="url" class="form-control"}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <div class="btn-group">
         <div {{action "save"}} class="btn btn-primary">{{icon "floppy-save"}} Save</div>
         {{#if confirmDelete}}
            <div {{action "delete"}} class="btn btn-danger">{{icon "trash"}} Are You sure?</div>
         {{else}}
            <div {{action "confirm"}} class="btn btn-danger">{{icon "trash"}} Delete</div>
         {{/if}}
         </div>

         <div {{action "reset"}} class="btn btn-default"> {{icon "ban-circle"}} Cancel</div>
    </div>

    {{else}}

    <div class="btn-group pull-right btn-group-xs">
        {{#if view.hover }}
        <div {{action "edit"}} class="btn btn-default">{{icon "cog"}}</div>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
    <dt>
        <span class="text-muted">{{resource_icon type}}</span> {{text}}
    </dt>
    {{#if description}}
    <dd class="text-muted"  style="margin-bottom:1em">
        {{markdown description}}
    </dd>
    {{/if}}
    <hr>
{{/if}}
```

#### Create Resource Template

```
<h3>Create Resource</h3>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-2">
            <small>Type</small>
                {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="resourceTypes" classNames="form-control" valueBinding="type"}}
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-10">
                <small>Resource Name</small>
                {{input valueBinding="text" class="form-control"}}
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-12">
            <br>
                <small>Description</small>
                {{textarea valueBinding="description" rows="5" class="form-control"}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-12">
                <br>
                <small>URL,File Name, or Vimeo ID</small>
                {{input valueBinding="url" class="form-control"}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

         <div {{action "save"}} class="btn btn-primary">{{icon "floppy-save"}} Save</div>
         <div {{action "test"}} class="btn btn">Test</div>
         {{#link-to "resources.index" class="btn btn-default" }}  {{icon "ban-circle"}} Cancel {{/link-to}}
         <br><br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I am not sure if this is the correct way to handle this but basically the parent model needed to be reloaded once the child model was created and saved. So like this

```
save: function() {
  var self = this;

  var resource = this.store.createRecord('resource',{
     property: 'property',
     relatedProperty: this.get('model'),
     //etc
  });

  resource.save().then(function(){
      self.get('model').reload();
  },function(){
     //do stuff because the resource didnt save
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some general notes first.

1. With this much code, everyone's going to have a much easier time helping you if you provide a JSBin or something.  It's a bit of extra work for you, but you're asking for help, and this is a lot to just mentally parse and run.  Personally, it was some extra overhead for me because you didn't include your router, so I had to do a pass just to try to figure out how badge and resource were related.
2. When you're using an ObjectController with the route model set to a new record, with input helpers, you shouldn't need to do all of that setting.  That's why you specified those value bindings on the helpers.  But when you do need to set a bunch of properties, you can just do that all at once with something like `record.setProperties({prop1: prop1Value, prop2: prop2Value ...});` and save yourself a lot of typing.
3. I don't understand why you're using `resourcesIndex` as a ResourcesCreateController need.    To actually answer your question, it might work to specify just `'resources'` as a need

then use something like

```
resource.save().then(function(record){
  self.get("controllers.resources").pushObject(record);
  self.transitionToRoute("resources.index", badge); // I don't know if this makes any sense because you didn't show your router, but at the very least, don't use self.badge, or even self.get("badge"), because badge is already accessible in this scope.
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help. The initial code I posted was pretty straight forward but it quickly ballooned into something that needed a jsbin. Thank you for everything, ill put everything in a jsbin and see if I can recreate the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be nice to see your Model definitions, and even better if you had a jsbin setup showing the problem.

You could always try hooking it up on createRecord.

```
 App.ResourcesCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
     return this.store.createRecord('resource', {badge: this.modelFor('badge')});
    }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still seeing the same problem. I have added the model definitions. I will attempt to create a jsbin but the project that I am building would be quite large to convert.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Not yet, I am still in the process of making a jsbin

Comment: I posted a working solution. Thanks for your help. The parent model needed to be reloaded once the child resource was created.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you create the new resource, you aren't putting it in the store. You should try something like `this.store.createRecord(resource)` then instead of your `resource.save`, do a `this.store.commit.`

I'm not entirely sure I'm right. But it may be a possibility.

Comment: According to the [emberjs docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/) and the transition doc for [ember data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) it is supposed to be model.save(). I tried commit and I got an error message saying that there was no commit command.

Comment: He is using the store to create the resource, he then assigns it to the model of the view, then saves it later.